# Update dataframe column values if values in another column are in list

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to update the column of a dataframe, based on the values of another column and their presence in a list.

```
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane','Theresa', 'Alice'], 
                   'category': ['black','red','green','yellow']})

lst = ['Jane','Theresa']
```

So the new category for these two names would be, for example, 'white'.

I understand I can create a new column and then delete the previous on but I was wondering if there was a way to do this directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of it.

```
for name in lst:
     df.loc[(df['user']==name), 'category'] = 'white'
```

As per documentation, df.loc allows you to "access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array", which in this case corresponds to the entries for which the 'user' column matches a name in your list. Finally, we assign 'white' to the 'category' column.

```
df
```

[image]